# How to fix youtube-dl error : unable to open for writing: [Errno 21] Is a directory?

Tags: youtube-dl

I am trying to use `youtube-dl` to download a video from youtube to a directory and this error pops up:

```
$ youtube-dl -o ~/Videos http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0YiWsAM0O8
[youtube] P0YiWsAM0O8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] P0YiWsAM0O8: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] P0YiWsAM0O8: Extracting video information
[youtube] P0YiWsAM0O8: Downloading MPD manifest
WARNING: Your copy of avconv is outdated and unable to properly mux separate video and audio files, youtube-dl will download single file media. Update avconv to version 10-0 or newer to fix this.
ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/sami/Videos
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and the `youtube-dl` version 2017.06.05

Answer (score 13):

The `-o` option tells `youtube-dl` how to format the target *path and name* of your videos (not only the directory). Kind of counter-intuitive.

From the `youtube-dl(1)` [README](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#filesystem-options) or [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/youtube-dl.1.html):

> `-o`, `--output TEMPLATE`
>
> Output filename template, see the "OUTPUT TEMPLATE" for all the info

So you need something like:

```sh
youtube-dl -o "$HOME/Videos/%(title)s.%(ext)s" 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0YiWsAM0O8'
```

To specify something other than the default of `%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s`. I am guessing you most likely want to just move into your `~/Videos` folder and run `youtube-dl` with no options there though.

Comment: Btw, the default output path pattern is `%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I was just quoting from the man page

Comment: Im using Windows 10 and have the current path pattern %%(playlist)s/%%(chapter_number)02d - %%(chapter)s/%%(playlist_index)02d - %%(title)s.%%(ext)s but still receive the same error. Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Even in `/tmp` and with `sudo`. Any ideas ? `youtube-dl` is installed from snap

Comment: Nice tune, bro..